# Issues while calling Wikipedia Api using node.js

Tags: node.js, request, wikipedia-api

```
 var request = require("request");
 var query = "english";
 var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="${query}"&format=json";
 request(url, function (err, response, body) {
     if(err){
         var error = "cannot connect to the server";
         console.log(error);
     } else {
         console.log("body:",body);
     }
 });
```

I have written this code in code editor.
I have used `npm install request --save` but while running the program in console, it is displaying only `"body:"` not the content .

Please suggest what changes are required.

Comment: Instead of console.log('body:',body). 
Do console.log(response).
I think you would get your array/JSON there.

Comment: no content is not displayed in response

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your code. Change the part before the request function to the following:

```
var request = require('request')
var query = 'english'
var url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=${query}&format=json`
```

Comment: this same program can be used in lambda function of aws to call wiki api?

Comment: If you got the answer you should put it as an answer in this forum.

Comment: But i am getting the answer for query. i should get the JSON for english. query is my variable

Comment: can u help me??

Comment: What version of node.js are you using @KomalGupta? Try to use the newer version (at least 8) and make sure the quotes around the value of url is a tick instead of a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Your main code should not be in an else statement. It should simply be in the function and have the error in the if statement.

```
var request = require('request');
var query = 'english';
var url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=${query}&format=json`
request(url, function (err, response, body) {
  console.log('body:',body);
  if(err){
    var error = "cannot connect to the server";
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: But i am getting the JSON for query not for english. Query is my variable

Comment: please help me in this

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: in output i am getting the JSON for 'query' not 'english' .Query is any variable in which we give word for answer